# Arrow/Vector Notation in R language

Tags: r

Is there some functionality to do arrow notation in R? I'm looking for something similar to `hat(x)`, `tilde(x)`, `dot(x)`, `ring(x)` and `bar(xy)`, mentioned in *http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/grDevices/html/plotmath.html.*

[Update]

By "arrow notation", I mean vector notation. Like the one in the following image.

[image: http://abstractmath.org/MM/MMOtherSymbols_files/eq0001M.gif]

Comment: Sounds like you might want to try ?plotmath.

Comment: Is there an example somewhere of what you mean by "arrow notation"? There are functions for arrows listed on the page you linked to.

Comment: By "arrow notation", I meant vector notation. Like http://abstractmath.org/MM/MMOtherSymbols_files/eq0001M.gif. I'll update my question.

Comment: Do you find the solution? I am also trying to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`demo(plotmath)` shows you the possibilities for drawing arrows in plot text.  Examples include:

```
x %=>% y # double right arrow for implies
x %->% y # single right arrow for function mapping
```

---

Update based upon the comment:

There is no arrow accent available.  You can hack one using `atop(phantom(0) %->% phantom(0), x)`, but it doesn't look great because the arrow is too high up.

Comment: Thanks. But I'm more looking for something similar to hat(x), but instead of a ^ sign, it shows -> on the top of the variable.